# How to activate Wayland before arriving at login screen?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg, wayland

I have a boot video problem Ubuntu 18.04-4 installs in safe graphics mode only, but boots to purple screen where mouse works (NVIDIA)  that can be solved by enabling Wayland

How can I  enable Wayland? The gear icon wont appear on my login screen. 
I also tried editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and commenting `WaylandEnable=...` or putting `WaylandEnable=true` but I dont ever get the gear icon, and also `echo $XGD_SESSION_TYPE` gives me x11 always even after reboot.

Comment: Do you use gdm3? If yes, as a privileged administrator user use your text editor to change the configuration file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.
FROM: WaylandEnable=false
TO: #WaylandEnable=false

I did this in my installation for different purposes, buy I have Ubuntu v20 04, check it in your version

Comment: You can edit the file as sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Comment: @LorenzKeel ain't this option simply a way to enable the Wayland option in the login menu? Or it indeed makes Wayland load on startup?

Comment: In a Virtual Machine where I set the automatic login (i.e I skip the login screen, I don't need it in a VM), the above settings brings me directly to the desktop in a wayland session. Before changed it, I went directly to desktop in a X11 session.

Comment: @LorenzKeel just tried here both putting the entire thing as a comment and letting `WaylandEnable=true` but I always land on x11